# problems with implicit intents

Tags: android

now i am learning intent filters..I got some some example like view contacts,make call.But all in those examples they used default  in android.manifestfile..

```
< intent-filter >
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" >
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" >
< /intent-filter>
```

this is ok for single .java file application.If i am using  implicit intent in my second activity, then how will be the  of my second activity manifest file?..just take the examplw of view contact....
Intent contact=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
my class name is ViewContacts.java and package name is com.phone.contact...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intent filter is specified within the Activity tag and you can specify multiple filters per activity.

```
<activity android:name=".activities.WaypointMap" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/Theme.NoBackground">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
<activity android:name=".activities.WaypointList" android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

Comment: .thanks for the reply..my doupt is I can write default intent-filter for first activity....But for second activity i don't have any idea...can u plz write that piece of code?...

Comment: Like I said, just add the intent filter to the Activity tag in the Manifest.  I am editing my response.